# Observing simultaneous changes in multiple objects with KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I have a `LineView` class that displays a line between two points. A `LineView` is essentially just a rectangular view with `thickness` representing height, and the locations of its `startPoint` and `endPoint` determine the width of the rectangle as well as the rotation that I apply (using `CGAffineTransform`) to the rectangle.

```
@interface LineView : UIView
@property (nonatomic) float thickness;
@property (nonatomic, strong) (PointView *)startPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) (PointView *)endPoint;
```

The `PointView` class defines a moving point on the screen. Since I want the line to always be displayed between its start point and its end point, I'm having the `LineView` observe the `center` properties of both `startPoint` and `endPoint`, like so:

```
- (void)setStartPoint:(PointView *)startPoint
{
    // Un-observe previous startPoint
    [_startPoint removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center"];
    _startPoint = startPoint;
    // Observe new startPoint
    [_startPoint addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:0 context:nil];
    [self updateLine];
}
```

and `(void)setEndPoint:(PointView *)endPoint` is defined similarly. So whenever either `center` property changes, I want to update the line:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if (![keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"])
    {
        return;
    }
    if (object == self.startPoint || object == self.endPoint)
    {
        [self updateLine];
    }
}
```

And here's `(void)updateLine:`

```
- (void)updateLine
{
    CGPoint startPoint = self.startPoint.center;
    CGPoint endPoint = self.endPoint.center;

    // tangent vector
    CGPoint tangent = cgpSubtract(endPoint, startPoint);

    // determine the angle of the tangent vector
    float angle = cgpAngle(tangent);
    // determine the length of the tangent vector
    float length = cgpLength(tangent);

    // frame is undefined when transform is not identity
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    // set frame.origin to startPoint, and frame.size to length and thickness
    self.frame = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, length, self.thickness);
    // rotate the view so that the line properly connects startPoint and endPoint
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The `cgp` functions are just static methods I've defined to perform simple `CGPoint` math.

So whenever `startPoint` or `endPoint` moves around the screen, the `center` property changes of the moving point(s), and the `LineView` observes this change and calls `updateLine` to update itself.

Now let's say we have the `startPoint` and `endPoint` move around the screen as time passes. In fact, we have a `Timeline` class with a `currentTime` property:

```
@interface Timeline : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) float currentTime;
...
```

and the `PointView` class is set up to observe this `currentTime` property, and changes its `center` position whenever `currentTime` changes.

In this way, `PointView` depends on `Timeline`, and `LineView` depends on two `PointView`s, but `LineView` does not have a dependency on `Timeline`. It doesn't need to know what the `currentTime` is, all it needs to be aware of is the locations of the `center`s of its start point and end point. This is good design, right?

So what happens, then, is when `currentTime` changes, `startPoint.center` and `endPoint.center` both change, and then `updateLine` of the `LineView` object is called twice. Ideally, I'd only want `updateLine` to be called once, since I really only need to update the line once to reflect changes made "simultaneously" to both points. Is there a good way to do this?

In this example calling `updateLine` twice doesn't seem to be that big of a deal. But what if I define some sort of `PolygonView` defined by, say, 100 `PointView`s? Then when I update the `currentTime`, all 100 `center`s of all 100 `PointView`s are updated, and this in turn calls `updatePolygon` 100 times, setting the `frame` and `transform` properties 100 times, which seems really inefficient.

So the main question here is, for an object that observes multiple other objects, how can I have this object update only once when `n` observed objects are changed "simultaneously", rather than `n` times?

I realize that the word "simultaneous" isn't exactly appropriate here, since the changes are not handled simultaneously; each `PointView` is updated sequentially at runtime. However, I can't find a better word to describe this situation.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but don't forget to pass a context pointer, and make sure you call super appropriately in observeValueForKeyPath. You mention a bunch of dependancies, but don't mention implementing +keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key> .....?

Comment: @quellish isn't calling `super` in `observeValueForKeyPath` necessary only if the superclass implements the method? `LineView` inherits from `UIView`, and nothing in the `UIView` class hierarchy seems to implement this method.

Comment: NSKeyValueObserving is an informal protocol on NSObject. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:

Comment: I was looking at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE
where it says "Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*. NSObject does not implement the method." Is it better practice to just make a call to the superclass method anyway?

Comment: Yup, always call super - this is why the context pointer is important. Example: https://gist.github.com/quellish/bc7ecfd885c97c60d4c2#file-kvo